# Two divs with position absolute overlapping with each other

Tags: html, css

I am totally new to css and want to create two divs with position absolute.
Here is the css:

```
.divcontent {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}
.divcontent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px
}
```

and here is the html:

```
    <div id="div1" class="divcontent">
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="divcontent">
        <span>Some other text</span>
    </div>
```

Now both these divs are overlapping each other. I want to place div2 in bottom of div1

Comment: Why you want to use position:abslute, since you don't want to overlap both divs over each other.

Comment: As I said, I am totally new. Can you tell me what should I use instead?

Comment: If I remove position:absolute then the divs move to the top of the screen. I want them at the bottom

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle for this issue so we can help you further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done as such because `position: absolute` is designed to allow you to specify an absolute position for an element.

You can use either `top` or `bottom` with member elements to place it accordingly.

```
 <div id="div1" class="divcontent">
        <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="divcontent" style="bottom: 5px;">
        <span>Some other text</span>
    </div>
```

[Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/7b8c5gf4/2/)

If you want it a bit generic, then create a CSS `padding-bottom-05 { padding-bottom: 5px; }`

then with html

```
<div id="div2" class="divcontent padding-bottom-05">
```

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing. What if instead of creating two divs I create multiple spans in one div but in that case <br /> not working, I am getting the text in the same line. i.e <div class="divContent"><span>1</span><span>2</span></div>

Comment: span and div won't work in the same way. DIV is a block element

Answer (score 3):

Here is one method, translate div2 down by 100% of it's height:

```css
.divcontent {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 5%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8
}

.divcontent:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.divcontent span {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #4D575D;
  margin: 0 3px
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="divcontent">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="divcontent">
  <span>Some other text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You targeted .divcontent:nth-child(1) {} which isn't/wasn't right. So positive 100% is fine, with the right selector.

Comment: Some text needs to stay where it is, but you moved it above, not vice versa. :) The point is to target the div2, which is the one that "needs" to be moved.

Comment: Np, gave you an upvote because it's clean and straightforward.